# run GO111MODULE=on go install . ./cmd/... in cloud init

Tags: go, server, cloud, cloud-init

I have a bash script which is deployed with cloud init,  my bash script contains the following part of code

```
GO111MODULE=on go install . ./cmd/...
```

when running my bash script directly in the terminal of the deplyed server, it works as expected. But when i run it with runcmd in the cloud config, this part of the script:

```
GO111MODULE=on go install . ./cmd/...
```

does not get executed, anyone knows why?

```
    runcmd:
  - [ bash, /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh ]
```

Answer (score 2):

A proper shell execution in `runcmd` would be (as seen in [Cloud config examples](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html)):

```
- [ bash, -c, /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh ]
```

or:

```
- [ /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh ]
```

Assuming your script starts with a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) `#!/bin/bash`

Plus, you need to add any environment variable inside the script, as  [Cloud config examples](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html) do not include any obvious way to set them.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
export GO111MODULE=on
export ...
```

Comment: myscript.sh gets executed with runcmd, but the part with GO111MODULE=on, does not get executed, or it does get executed but with wrong paths, not sure!! running myscript.sh directly on the server, works fine

Comment: @iFadi I would add `export GO111MODULE=on` *inside* your script `myscript.sh`, and make sure said script is called with `bash -c`.

Comment: thx for the tip, still it did not work, i found under /var/log/syslog the following error after the GO command gets executed:
`build cache is required, but could not be located: GOCACHE is not defined and neither $XDG_CACHE_HOME nor $HOME are defined`

i'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: @iFadi I have edited my answer to include environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the tip from VonC, i was able to fix the issue. i added the following to myscript.sh

```
GOCACHE=/root/.cache/go-build
export GOCACHE
export GO111MODULE=on
go install . ./cmd/...


runcmd:
- [ bash, -c, /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh ]
```

the script now deploys and runs from cloud-init.