# cloud-init runcmd (using MAAS)

Tags: bash, cloud-init, ipmi, maas

I'm unable to run bash scripts in "runcmd:" that aren't inline.

```
runcmd:
    - [ bash, -c, echo "=========hello world=========" >>foo1.bar ]
    - [ bash, -c, echo "=========hello world=========" >>foo2.bar ]
    - [ bash, -c, /usr/local/bin/foo.sh ]
```

The first two lines are successfully run on the deployed Ubuntu instance. However, the foo.sh doesn't seem to run.

Here is /usr/local/bin/foo.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "=========hello world=========" >>foosh.bar
```

foo.sh has executable permissions for root and resides on the MAAS server.

I've looked at the following but they don't seem to sort out my issue:

- [Cannot make bash script work from cloud-init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46297120/cannot-make-bash-script-work-from-cloud-init)
- [run GO111MODULE=on go install . ./cmd/... in cloud init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70072004/run-go111module-on-go-install-cmd-in-cloud-init)
- https://gist.github.com/aw/40623531057636dd858a9bf0f67234e8

Comment: What happens if you run that same command from the command line?

Comment: @larsks If I run the command in the foo.sh on the deployed server/OS, it runs properly.

Comment: But if you run the *same commandline* you have in your cloud-init configuration? `bash -c /usr/local/bin/foo.sh`

Comment: Yes...It doesn't run because the file foo.sh isn't there. I was under the impression that cloud-init would take it from the "maas server node" and run it on the deployed machine...any idea how to resolve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything you run using `runcmd` must already exist on the filesystem. There is no provision for automatically fetching something from a remote host.

You have several options for getting files there. Two that come to mind immediately are:

- You could embed the script in your cloud-init configuration using the [`write-files` directive](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html#writing-out-arbitrary-files):

  ```
  write_files:
    - path: /usr/local/bin/foo.sh
      permissions: '0755'
      content: |
        #!/bin/bash
        echo "=========hello world=========" >>foosh.bar

  runcmd:
    - [bash, /usr/local/bin/foo.sh]
  ```
- You could fetch the script from a remote location using `curl` (or similar tool):

  ```
  runcmd:
    - [curl, -o, /usr/local/bin/foo.sh, http://somewhere.example.com/foo.sh]
    - [bash, /usr/local/bin/foo.sh]
  ```